# Qual a finalidade do comando sizeof?

Tags: c

Qual é a finalidade do comando `sizeof` na **linguagem C**?
 Eu sei que posso usar ele para alocação de memória e criar vetores de forma dinâmica da seguinte maneira `vetInt = malloc(sizeof(int) * tamanho);`.
 Fora isso este comando tem outra função?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O operador **sizeof** indica o tamanho, em bytes, do tipo da variável. 
Esse operador permite que você evite especificar tamanhos de dados dependentes do computador em seus programas.

Quando você diz:

> *Eu sei que posso usar ele para alocação de memoria e criar vetores de forma dinâmica da seguinte maneira* *`vetInt = malloc(sizeof(int) * tamanho);`*

Você deve ter em mente que o comando que realmente faz a alocação de memória é o **malloc** e não o **sizeof**, ele apenas devolve para a função **malloc** qual o tamanho da variável que ela deve alocar de memória.

Comment: Obrigado por esclarecer esta minha duvida.

Comment: A mais alguma utilidade para este comando?

Comment: @DenerCarvalho Eu desconheço outra.

Comment: Gostaria de fazer uma correção. Sizeof não devolve o tamanha necessário, mas sim o tamanho da variável.

Answer (score 2):

Sempre que precisares de saber o tamanho dum objecto (ou o número de sub-objectos) deves usar o `sizeof`.

Por exemplo, para copiar um array para uma zona de memória alocada

```
int arr[52];
p = malloc(sizeof arr);
if (p) {
    memcpy(p, arr, sizeof arr);
    // work with p
    free(p);
}
```

No exemplo acima, podes perfeitamente substituir o `52` por uma constante definida com um `#define` e usar essa constante (com uma multiplicação por `sizeof *arr`) no `malloc()` e `memcpy()`, mas, a meu ver, esta maneira é mais agradável.

Outro exemplo, para ordenar um array

```
int arr[52];
// preenche arr
qsort(arr, sizeof arr / sizeof *arr, sizeof *arr, fxcmp);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação.